How to change the R execute that Rscript cited in back-end in Linux?
When you use the following command to run a R script in terminal
Rscript --verbose <your_R_script_file> 

it will display something like this

/share/home/user/bin/mambaforge/envs/py310/lib/R/bin/R --no-echo --no-restore --file=<your_R_script_file>

now I'm wondering if there is a way to let Rscript use another R execute other than /share/home/user/bin/mambaforge/envs/py310/lib/R/bin/R ?
I'm asking this question because recently the administrator changed my user name (and of course my home directory and R execute also changed) . Now I can't run R script in terminal. Rscript kept throw

Rscript execution error: No such file or directory


if you know the location of the Rscript that you want to be executed, use that with its absolute path. eg /user/bin/R3.6/Rscript --verbose file.R

Isn't this more of a conda/mamba configuration or activation issue? And considering that mambaforge is deprecated, perhaps it's a good time to switch to miniforge and verify that your environments really are reproducible?

@Onyambu I used "which" command to locate the Rscript and used the absolute path. It doesn't work

@margusl  After my home directory was renamed the mamba environment can not be activated at the beginning. However after I "find/replace" all my old user name to the new one in .bashrc, the activation issue was fixed.  I didn't know it was deprecated until your comment . Probably you are right
